# why df.residual returns "logical" when using lm.fit in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have three directories and there are five files in each directory. those files are matrix(rasters) . I want to compute the regression equation between the corresponding columns of the files.

```
  fun <- function(x1, x2, y) {
  keep <- !(is.na(x1) | is.na(x2) | is.na(y))
  if (sum(keep) > 1) {
    res <- lm.fit(cbind(1,x1[keep], x2[keep]), y[keep])$df.residual
  } else {
    res <- c(NA, NA, NA)
  }
    res
}


res <- array(res, dim=c(1,dim(dat1)[2:3]));  res <- aperm(res, c(2,3,1))
res
# [1,] Logical,3 Logical,3 Logical,3 Logical,3 Logical,3 Logical,3 Logical,3 Logical,3 Logical,3      
#    Logical,3 Logical,3 Logical,3
```

Comment: Your download link is useless if one doesn't speak french. You should educate yourself how to create a **minimal** reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your function to

```
fun <- function(x1, x2, y) {
  keep <- !(is.na(x1) | is.na(x2) | is.na(y))
  if (sum(keep) > 1) {
    res <- lm.fit(cbind(1,x1[keep], x2[keep]), y[keep])$df.residual
  } else {
    res <- NA
  }
  res
}
```

`df.residual` is a single value for each fit, but you try to combine that with a vector of three `NA` values. Consequently, `mapply` doesn't invoke `simplify2array` and you end up with a list.

PS: You should change `if (sum(keep) > 1)` to a bigger limit if you want to fit a three parameter model. Two observations are not enough to fit this model.